# Как сделать кнопку со скошенными краями?

Tags: css, hover

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую кнопку? Главное чтобы при наведении, background сверху вниз летел.
Как вот на этом [сайте](http://www.shipyard.lv/), но там плохо сделано.

И что делать еслю меню многоуровневое, чтобы при клике открывается в низу другой список горизонтальный?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.skew {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.skew li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.skew li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: top 150ms;
}
.skew li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transition: color 150ms;
}
.skew li:hover:before {
  top: 0%;
}
.skew li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="skew">
  <li><a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, вот тоже самое почти делал :), спасибо!

Comment: А что делать если меню многоуровневое? В Теге <li> еще один тег <ul>

Answer (score 1):

Как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/8rp6yqrj/

```
<div class='menu'>
    <div class='btn'><span>Menu</span></div>
    <div class='btn'><span>Menu</span></div>
</div>

.menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background: #eee;
}

.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #900;
}
.btn span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.btn:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    top: 0; left: 0;
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
.btn:hover:before {
    background: #900;
}
.btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```